# Haar Feature-based Cascade Classifier XML file argument

Tags: xml, cascade, face-detection

I'm working with face detection of Haar Feature-based Cascade Classifier. I have searched a lots but I still haven't found the exactly answer for the left_val and right_val in XML file (like this)

```
  <_>
        <!-- root node -->
        <feature>
            <rects>
                <_>3 7 14 4 -1.</_>
                <_>3 9 14 2 2.</_></rects>
            <tilted>0</tilted></feature>
        <threshold> 4.0141958743333817e-003 </threshold>
        <left_val> 0.0337941907346249 </left_val>
        <right_val> 0.8378106951713562 </right_val></_></_>
  <_>
```

The left_val and right_val are the return value of a feature ( alpha(i) * h(i) in Viola-jones paper), is it true. And if so, because h(i) is -1 or 1 so we must have left_val = - right_val but in face it isn't true. Can you guys give me some explanation to understand that?
Thank you for your help!  Sorry my English is not so good